# How can I initialize firebase a spring-boot application hosted on google app-engine

Tags: java, spring, firebase, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I'm working on an application using spring-boot as my backend which stores data in Firebase realtime database.

The app works fine when I run it locally while saving data to the database however when I deploy it on app-engine, I keep on getting this error when I send a request using Postman 
[image: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.]

I have followed the steps described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup to set up the project.
I used the service account credentials and referenced them in my main java class as follows:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/credentials.json");



    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setProjectId("my project id")
            .setDatabaseUrl("my database url")
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

I also tried saving the path as an environment variable as follows:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/credentials.json"
```

It still didn't work on app-engine.
Someone save me

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky one. Env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` only works on Google Cloud Engine project not on AppEngine.

One solution is to make the credentials file part of the `war` and fetch the file using `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream`

One example where I have used this pattern in a Maven Project.

1. POM file to make credentials file part of WAR: https://github.com/yagnyam-in/sms-gateway-backend/blob/master/pom.xml#L262
2. Fetching Credentials in source code: https://github.com/yagnyam-in/sms-gateway-backend/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/in/yagnyam/sms_gateway/services/FirebaseService.kt#L38

**Warning:** If you are pushing this war file to any artifactory site, credentials file is exposed to everyone as now its part of war file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. The problem was not with credentials, it was with the packaging and I finally got a solution. check my answer for more info

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution.
What brought the problem was the way I packaged and deployed my project.
The jar file in app-engine was not getting updated everytime I deployed a new version and it was because of the command that I used. So the error was displayed because my very first version didn't have credentials.

The command that didn't update the jar file:

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

The command that updated my jar file:

```
mvn clean package appengine:deploy -P cloud-gcp
```

I hope it helps someone else.